# is it possible to run ubuntu phone os in unoffical mobiles?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, ubuntu-touch, phone

i am using lg spirit it has 1 gb of ram,Android OS, v5.0.1 (Lollipop),Quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A7 - H420,Mediatek MT6582 - H420,    Geo-tagging, touch focus, face detection.

Comment: replay me with positive answers pls

Comment: Could you please define "safe" and please [edit] your answer if you want to add information or clarify something? Thanks.

Comment: Your phone is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

> is it safe to run ubuntu phone os in unoffical mobiles?

No, they are called "unofficial" for a reason. Installing an OS that is not intended for that system is never safe. It can brick your system and depending on how proficient you are in restoring android might make it actually a to.

But that is also sort of the only risk you run. When you get it installed all will be fine.

After the edit:

> is it possible to run ubuntu phone os in unoffical mobiles?

Yes, but you need specific firmware for the phone. Before you attempt it: Ubuntu touch does not run on a LG Spirit.

Comment: shall i change my lg spirit firmare to lg optimum to run ubuntu.is it possible.comment pls

Comment: see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices that one is being worked on so: no, for now.